# Why is it only printing one word of the text file rather than the whole text file to a html file

Tags: c++, command-line

I am currently working on a project that converts a .txt file into a .xhtml file using the command line properties. Specially, this program converts an ASCII text file to an xhtml 1.0 file containing the same textual content as the original ASCII text file. The problem I seem to have is when I open the .html file to read the content from the old .txt file only one word from the file is being read into the html file. Can anyone explain why this is so? The help would be much appreciated.Thank you in advance.

```
//Programmer:
    //Date: March 9 2015
    //Purpose: converts an old style text file into any format
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <string>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <map>

    using namespace std;

    // getWord function to read in all words
    istream& getWord(istream& is, string& word)
    {
        // find the beginning of the word (ie . eat all the non alphas)
        char ch;

        while (is.get(ch))
        {

            if (isalpha(ch))
                break;
        }
        // quit if no word found
        if (!is)
            return is;

        string buffer;
        buffer += ch;   // put the valid alpha onto the buffer
        while (is.get(ch))
        {
            if (isalpha(ch))
                buffer += ch;
            else
                break;
        }
        if (is)
            is.unget();
        if (is.eof())
            is.clear();
        if (is)
            //word = buffer;        // put the complete buffer into the word so it can be returned by reference. 
            //This does a copy + destroy!!
            swap(word, buffer);         // C++98(swap owner, then destory the old)
        word = std::move(buffer);   // C++ 11 
        return is;
    }

    int main(int argc, char* argv[])

    {
        ifstream infile(argv[1]);
        char ch = 0;
        while (infile.get(ch)){
            cout.put(ch);
        }

        // print out all the command line arguments
        for (size_t i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
        {
            string s = (string)argv[i];
            cout << s << endl;
        }
        //if input file is at location 1 in the command line
        string input = argv[1];
        for (size_t i = 0; i < input.size(); ++i)
        {
            cout.put(input[i]);
        }
        cout << endl;


    // Creating the html output file
        ofstream out("title.html");
        out << "<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999//xhtml\"xml:lang=\"en\">" << endl;
        out << "<head>" << endl;
        out << "<meta http - equiv = \"Content-Type\" content = \"text/html; charset=UTF-8\" />" << endl;
        out << "<title>" << argv[1] << "</title>" << endl;
        out << "</head>" << endl;
        out << "<body>" << argv[1] << endl;

        // extracting the words from the file and storing it in a container
        typedef map<string, unsigned> dictionary_type;
        dictionary_type words;

        // read the information in to find only words
        string word;
        while (getWord(infile, word))
        {
            auto loc = words.find(word);
            if (loc == words.end())
                words.insert(pair<string, int>(word, 1));
            else
                loc->second++;
        }
        //print out the container
        for (auto w : words)
            cout << w.first << ": " << w.second << endl;
        out << "</body>" << endl << "</html>";



    }
```

Comment: You're one third of the way from asking a good question, please post a small input file, the expected output, and what your program actually outputs.

Comment: Your basic problem is that your code isn't even vaguely similar to what you describe. Your code seems to be a conglomeration of two mostly unrelated pieces--one generates an HTML header/footer. The other tries to generate a count of words, such as you'd use to produce a histogram. None of it, however, does anything even vaguely similar to copying the input file through to the output, with the HTML header/footer added on at the ends. It doesn't even hint at doing the HTML escaping you'd need on the content either.

Comment: @user657267 my program doesn't actually spit anything out I'm using the command line properties to take a txt file named "The Republic by, Plato.txt" and send it to an xhtml file to be read(so I can open it in a browser when I click on it). The code im trying to implement should read (or try to read) all of the words in the txt file and copy that into the xhtml file. But its only giving my one word out of the whole text file. That's why in my code I'm making a call to argv[1] and its location(or index). Because at location 1 of the command line arguments I set the txt file to that location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see couple of problems:

1. You are reading the contents of the file first, echoing the contents to `std::cout`. After you are done with that, there is nothing to read from the file. Add a call to rewind the file and then read its contents again.

   ```
   infile.clear();  // Clear its state. Otherwise infile.eof() is true.
   infile.seekg(0); // rewind
   ```

Those lines need to go before

```
    while (getWord(infile, word))
```

2. You have the lines:

   ```
   if (is)
      swap(word, buffer);         // C++98(swap owner, then destory the old)
   word = std::move(buffer);   // C++ 11
   ```

   You need to use only one of them, not both. If you use both, `word` gets set to an empty string.